# Replace newline with double newline

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I have an `EditText` defined in which i'm allowing the user to type in his/her content.

When the user presses the newline key the `EditText` takes the cursor to a newline.

I do not want this to happen. I want to another blank line in between (like a paragraph).

I guess we have to use `TextWatcher` for this but I'm not sure about how to use it. Can someone guide me?

In short I want to replace a `\n` typed by the user into a `\n\n` on the fly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you want to detect when the user presses the "newline key", i suggest you to use a [KeyListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/KeyListener.html) instead of `TextWatcher`.

```
yourEditText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)  {
              // Here the user press the EnterKey (newline),
              // so you can add another extra line to your EditText.
              // Add the "\n" character to your text, to skip another line.
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

first set the text watcher listener to your editext

```
// Set Text Watcher listener
myEditText.addTextChangedListener(passwordWatcher);
```

also include this static class in your activity

```
private final TextWatcher passwordWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
//This means that the characters are about to be replaced with some new text.The text is uneditable. 
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            //Changes have been made, some characters have just been replaced. The text is uneditable.Use: when you need to see which characters in the text are new.
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

             //Changes have been made, some characters have just been replaced. now the text is editable. please do your replacement job here
//you can get the text from the "s". compare and replace "\n" with "\n\n" 



        }
    };
```

please have a look at this tutorial: [textwatcher example](http://javatechig.com/android/android-textwatcher-example)